# How to generate PDF with low memory on the server?

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I'm converting a table of my DB to PDF and I'm using the [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/).

First I have to convert my table to HTML and then I can convert to PDF, which use a lot of **memory** and I have a few resources on the server (256M for PHP max).

How can I pass a table that may have thousands of records to PDF with 256M memory max in PHP?

**Can I create a PDF page by page and in the end concatenate all pages?**

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to concatenate the pdf page from [this](http://garridodiaz.com/concatenate-pdf-in-php/) link.

```
require_once("tcpdf/tcpdf.php"); //ur workspaces
require_once("fpdi/fpdi.php");



class concat_pdf extends FPDI {
 var $files = array();
 function setFiles($files) {
      $this->files = $files;
 }
 function concat() {
      foreach($this->files AS $file) {
           $pagecount = $this->setSourceFile($file);
           for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) {
                $tplidx = $this->ImportPage($i);
                $s = $this->getTemplatesize($tplidx);
                $this->AddPage(’P', array($s['w'], $s['h']));
                $this->useTemplate($tplidx);
           }
      }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try fpdf (http://www.fdpf.org) or the related mpdf (http://www.mpdf1.com) as an alternative? Maybe they use less resources so they can run on your server. They do a good job in creating HTML to PDF output.

Comment: Yes I tried that and I have the same problem. I have a lot of records in my DB to put in my PDF file.

Comment: Is it somehow an option to create one page at a time? I'm sure there is a tool to merge different pages into one document